# Unable to use icons in Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, quasar-framework

I am trying to use some icons with `q-btn` but to no avail.

I am trying to use `mdi-v7` icons in my test project. To install the icons, I have followed the [official documentation](https://quasar.dev/options/installing-icon-libraries). In my `./quasar.config.js`, I have added the following

```
extras: [
  "mdi-v7",
  "roboto-font", // optional, you are not bound to it
  "material-icons", // optional, you are not bound to it
],
framework: {
  config: {},
  iconSet: "mdi-v7",
  plugins: [],
},
```

Now in my vue element I have tried to use the icons as followed

```
<div class="q-ml-sm row no-wrap items-center">
    <q-btn
      type="a"
      flat
      round
      :icon="mdiDeskLamp"
      @click="$q.dark.toggle()"/>
</div>
```

I have also imported the icons

```
import { mdiDeskLamp } from "@quasar/extras/mdi-v7";
```

But this gives me warning in console and no icon is shown.

```
[Vue warn]: Property "mdiDeskLamp" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

Furthermore if I use `icon="mdiDeskLamp` (instead of `:icon`) I don't get any icon displayed, but there is a weird **D** displayed

[image]

I am pretty sure this is a rookie mistake, being very new to the framework. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out. One should use `mdi-desk-lamp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the q-icon tag inside the q-button
for example:

`<q-btn> <q-icon name="mdiDeskLamp"/> </q-btn>`
Use this above code to add icon and style it accordingly.

For better reference
visit: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/button/